# How can I get user's group memberships included in the id token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an application that can successfully authenticate users through a B2C user flow policy and get an ID token in a JWT.

How can I update the user flow policy, so I get the user’s group membership as part of the ID token?

A link to documentation or concept would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Azure B2C , it is not possible to get the user's groups membership in the idToken unfortunately. The mentioned above  example by @rbrayb is using Custom policies with Identity Experience Framework , which is one way to go if you need to add the group memberships to the idToken.

Another way to do this is Manually call the Graph API ( using msal library/ Microsoft identity Client NUGET ) , with the objectId of the connected user and an access token in order to get the groups to which the user belong : In this case you will create a group for each role , affect the users to the right groups based on their role, by finding the users group , u know what's his role , here is an [example](https://damienbod.com/2021/09/06/using-azure-security-groups-in-asp-net-core-with-an-azure-b2c-identity-provider/) of implementing this kind of authorization on .Net5 web api and web App.

Answer (score 1):

This is the older [link](https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2019/05/06/using-groups-in-azure-ad-b2c/).

Basically, add the groups in Azure AD and extract them via Graph API.

There is also a [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/relying-party-rbac).

Comment: Thank you for help. Per my question, is there any way to include groups in the jwt id token? I just need a confirmation that it is NOT possible in B2C.

Comment: Bit confused. "This sample policy (along with the REST API service) demonstrates how to read user's groups, add the groups to JWT token and also prevent users from sign-in if they aren't members of one of the predefined security groups".

Comment: I see, let me dig dipper in the code.